# Where can I use Apple's SF Symbols?

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile, sf-symbols

I'm developing an app for iOS and Android using Flutter. Currently working on mock-ups, I'm using Apple's SF Symbols.

I was wondering if you could indeed use those icons for my apps but couldn't find the information on the web.

Anyone got the information ?

Answer (score 0):

SF Symbols is a set of over 3,100 symbols that you can use in your app. They’re aligned and configurable in a wide range of weights and scales to adapt to your designs. As they are integrated into the San Francisco system font, they automatically ensure optical vertical alignment with text for all weights and sizes.[Please read this guide for More detail](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/sf-symbols-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if you could indeed use those icons for my apps but couldn't find the information on the web.

From the [Xcode/SDKs license agreement](https://www.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/xcode.pdf):

> 2.13 System-Provided Images The system-provided images and symbols owned by Apple and documented as such in Apple's Human Interface
> Guidelines for iOS, watchOS, iPadOS, tvOS, and/or macOS
> (“System-Provided Images”) are licensed to You solely for the purpose
> of developing Applications for Apple-branded products that run on the
> system for which the image was provided...

Consult with an actual lawyer if you have any question about what that means, but to my un-lawyerly eye, it says that Apple owns the "System-Provided Images" (which must surely include SF Symbols) and that the agreement doesn't cover using them on non-Apple platforms. So you can use them in your iOS app, but not in your Android app unless you secure permission from them in some other way. Be sure to read the license; there are additional restrictions not quoted above that you should know about, e.g. you can't use them in your app's icon, etc.